# insert into child row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

can anyone help

I need to make a todo list in CodeIgniter-3.1.0, with tables and it gives me

> > A Database Error Occurred
> >
> > Error Number: 1452
>
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

[image: table and relations]

I want to insert in USER_LIST id from user so that it can connect with the id of the list. So primary key is user_id in users table and foreign key is us_id in table user_list.

**model**

```
public function us_lis($user_id)
    {
    $data = array('us_id' =>$user_id);
    $this->db->insert('user_list',$data);
    }
```

**Controller**

```
        $this->db->select('user_id');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('email', $_SESSION['email']);

        $user_id =$this->db->get()->row('user_id');

        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

      $this->model_lista->us_lis($user_id))
```

I hope someone can help and thanks in advance

Comment: make sure you have created the table using InnoDB is a storage engine

Comment: the value which is going to update or insert in child row not present in parent table, in this create a record in parent table and then do insert or update.

Comment: @aman while creating refrential integrity if table engines doesn't match. it won't create foreign child relation there itself.

Comment: then make sure you have unique foreign key constraint for each table

Comment: Yes, I created them using InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

I would first debug which query it has been executed using $this->db->last_query();
as mention in https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/db_driver_reference.html?highlight=last%20query#CI_DB_driver::last_query
 and as a habit i will cross check it in phpmyadmin or using cmd.

Where as I have one question as you mention in the controller part

```
$user_id = $this->db->get()->row('user_id');
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

What you want from the above two lines?

I will advice you to debug with the query generated.

Comment: sorry for the extra code,  I forgot to delete it after some changes

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks for trying to help me.
I gave up on that the table and added to `list table` another row `user_list_id`.
I know that this is not the correct way, but I do not have much time  .... sorry to bothering you and thanks for the tip about debugging query it will help me in the futur